# How to trigger angular 5 reactive form submission event from it's parent and grand parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I have three components - L1, L2 and L3 nested as depicted below:
[image: Component hierarchy]

Component L3 has a reactive form. I need to submit this form using the button present in component L2 and L1.

I tried using @Viewchild, but could not get the thing working. [Here is what I have tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-trigger-reactve-form-submission-from-parent-component).

Comment: Please share the code link, not just the deployed app link.

Comment: Sorry for that. Please refer here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-trigger-reactve-form-submission-from-parent-component. I have also updated the link in description.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it but creating public method for submitting form

```
public submitForm() {
  this.myForm.submitted = true;
}

<form [formGroup]='myForm' (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  // ...
</form>
```

Then by creating a reference variable of child component in parent and grandparent component and by using that ref variable, I can call it as

```
this.child.submitForm();
const valid = this.child.myForm.valid;
console.log(valid);
```

This should resolve your problem.